# how to override UIView.pointInside in swift?

Tags: swift, overriding

I'm trying to port my code from obj-c to swift, but experienced a lot of troubles.

one of the issues is overriding pointInside of a UIView class:

```
class MyView : UIView{
func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
    if point.x < 0 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true

    }
}}
```

if I don't add "override", I will get this error:

```
/xxx.swift:37:10: Method 'pointInside(_:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'pointInside:withEvent:' conflicts with method 'pointInside(_:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C selector
```

If I add "override", I will get this error:

```
/xxx.swift:37:19: Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

according to the doc, there should be a pointInside function

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:

Answer (score 1):

The function in UIKit is declared as

```
func pointInside(_ point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

The optionality (namely `UIEvent?`) needs to match.

This error message seems less than useful; you might want to [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org).

Answer (score 1):

You can override with conditional check also like:

```
class PassThroughView: UIView {

     override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
            for subview in subviews as [UIView] {
                if !subview.hidden && subview.alpha > 0 && subview.userInteractionEnabled && subview.pointInside(convertPoint(point, toView: subview), withEvent: event) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
```

Original post: [Swift: hitTest for UIView underneath another UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107849/swift-hittest-for-uiview-underneath-another-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2 syntax

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Note UIEvent must be optional to match the superclass