# How can I allow tapping on button outside cell frame?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have added cross button on the edge of collection view cell and half part of this button gets overlapped by the cell below it. How can I make the lower half for this button tappable?

[image]

**Edit:**
Is there anyway we can change the zposition for button or we can make it appear above the collection cells?

Comment: try overriding the `hitTest:` method. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107849/swift-hittest-for-uiview-underneath-another-uiview

Comment: this is bad design.

Comment: any suggestions for how can I improve this?